# Pythagoras theorem and ratio question

Tags: ratio

[https://gyazo.com/66f47546602b91315cceecd66927c129](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oW0M8.png)

In triangle PQR, X is a point on PQ. RX is perpendicular to PQ.
Work out the ratio PX : XQ. Give your answer in its simplest form.

---

---

---

---

---

---

Answer ________ : ________

Comment: What is the problem you are facing in the problem? Any thoughts?

Comment: It would be better if you showed your work too, including where and why you’re stuck.

Comment: Thank you for replying and sorry for not providing enough information. I simply don't get the question, when it says to work out the ratio of PX : XQ, I just don't get what I am supposed to do. I know what a ratio is but I am confused over what to do. Thank you for understanding

Comment: You need to use the Pythagorean Theorem to calculate the length of the sides $\overline{PX}$ and $\overline{XQ}$. Then, you can find the ratio of their sides by $\frac{\overline{PX}}{\overline{XQ}}$.

Comment: So the ratio will simply be: "The length of PX : The length of XQ"?

Comment: Yes, that’s what it’ll be.

Comment: You have to cancel the common factors from the numerator and denominator. If you get the answer as $4:12$, you have to cancel $4$ and report the answer as $1:3$

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers!

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Note that $\triangle PXR, \triangle QXR$ are right angled at $X$. Use the pythagorean theorem in both triangles:

$PX^2+RX^2=PX^2+16^2=PR^2=20^2\implies PX=\sqrt{20^2-16^2}$

$QX^2+RX^2=QX^2+16^2=QR^2=34^2\implies QX=\sqrt{34^2-16^2}$

Can you now work out the ratio $PX:QX=\frac{PX}{QX}$ in simplest terms?

Comment: The ratio would be 12:30 = 6:15 = 2:3

Comment: Yes, that's correct. $12:30::2:5$

Comment: You simplified the ratio incorrectly. $6:15 \implies 2:5$. Other than that, it’s correct.